# How does a file system like FastFile work?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, nodes, fastfile

I have 2 questions concerning the node array used by this file system which have `i` nodes to save the files.

Each `i`-node consists of

- a user ID (2 bytes)
- three timestamps (4 bytes each)
- protection bits (2 bytes)
- a reference count (2 bytes)
- a file type (2 bytes)
- size (4 bytes)

In addition, node-`i` contains

- 13 direct indexes
- an index to a level 1 index table
- an index to a level 2 index table
- an index to a level 3 index table

The system also stores the first 436 bytes of each file on node-`i`.

So, the questions are:

1. Let's assume that a sector of the disk has 512 bytes, and that any auxiliary index table occupies an entire sector, what is the maximum size of a file in this system?
2. Is there any benefit to the first 436 bytes of the file being stored on node-i?

Comment: Please check out [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to get good answers.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the first bytes of the file in the inode speeds up reads for files that can entirely fit in the inode itself. This is called [inlining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode#Inlining).

Because you mentioned 4 bytes (32 bits) are reserved for the file size, I'd expect `2^32 - 1` to be the max amount of sectors in a file.

From `man newfs` in OpenBSD:

> The maximum size of an FFS file system is 2,147,483,647 (2^31 - 1) of 512-byte blocks, slightly less than 1 TB. FFS2 file systems can be as large as 64 PB.